# How to downcast a List in Java?

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, type-alias

I want to hide generics with a People class:

```
interface People extends List<Person> {}
```

How I wanted to use it:

```
class PersonService {
    public People findAll() {
        ...
        List<Person> all = repository.findAll();
        People p = (People) all;
        return p;
    }
}
```

And the repo:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findAll();
}
```

`findAll()` throws `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to People` when casting. How can I cast a `List<Person>` to `People`? If not possible, how should I hide generics?

Comment: What's the value of trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: If you want to convert one type of list to another, you will have to actually write some code that converts it. It can't be done by casting, because an `ArrayList` is actually not an instance of `People`. Same as you can't by casting change a `String` to a `List` or an `Integer` to a `Set`. Casting isn't magic.

Comment: why would you want to do this? Seems like you want to wrap a list into a class no?

Comment: Casting `List<Person>` to `People` is ***not*** a downcast. Unclear what you're asking, or why.

Comment: What you are searching for is a type alias, which is not supported by the Java language. You cannot hide generics here. Just use `List<Person>` everywhere. Why do you wish to do it btw?

Comment: Well, People is shorter and more clear to me.

Comment: e.g. Task<People> is easy to read and to understand what the result is, Task<List<Person>> is rather confusing and requires more attention.

Comment: If `findAll()` returns a `List<Person>`, then that object will never be a `People` object, this is why your cast does not work. You may write a copy constructor in your `People` class that accepts a `List<Person>` argument. Then you could use this constructor to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class People that contains your list of Persons.

```
public class People {
   private List<Person> personList;
   .... getter / setters ....
}
```

That way the complexity is hidden and programmers can still access all details inside the People class if they need to.